# Workaround for passing a method into a method?

Tags: java, function, math, methods, parameters

I am looking for a way to pass a method as a parameter into another method.

I am currently trying to simulate the Newton's-method (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) in Java with the following code:

```
public class Newton {


// Iterationmethod
public void newtonCalc(double x0) {
    double x;

    // counter
    int i = 0;

    //Newton-Iteration for x0
    x = x0 - (y2(x0) / y2Deriv(x0));

    while (Math.sqrt(y2(x)*y2(x)) >= Math.pow(10, -10)){
        //Newton-Iteration x(n+1)
        x = x - (y2(x))/ y2Deriv(x);
        i++;
        System.out.printf("%d. %.11f\n",i,y2(x));
    }

    System.out.printf("%d steps were necessary for a resolution of 10^-10", i);
}

// Function for (2)
public static double y2(double x) {
    return Math.sin(x) / (1 - Math.tan(x));
}

// Derivative for (2)
public static double y2Deriv(double x) {
    return (Math.cos(x) + Math.sin(x) * Math.tan(x) * Math.tan(x))
            / ((Math.tan(x) - 1) * (Math.tan(x) - 1));
}

// Function for (4)
public static double y4(double x) {
    return Math.exp(-1/Math.sqrt(x));
}

// Derivative for (4)
public static double y4Deriv(double x) {
    return Math.exp(-1/Math.sqrt(x))/(2*Math.pow(x, 3d/2));
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    Newton newton = new Newton();
    newton.newtonCalc(1);
}
```

}

newtonCalc(x0) gets an x0 at wich the iteration should be started.
But the function (y2) now is hardcoded into this method. I want it to be flexible.
For example newtonCalc(double x0, Method y) to run the iteration for y starting at x0.
I have 2 different functions (y2 and y4 which are both functions from a excercise sheet from my lecture plus its derivatives y2Deriv and y4Deriv which are used in the Iterationmethod).

I know passing a method is not possible but i dont get any easy workaround.

Forgive me if this is unclear or i have missed any necessary information!

Regards,

Tak3r07

Answer (score 1):

It's entirely possible since Java 8, using [lambda expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay with pre-Java-8 methods, make an interface `Function` with member functions `eval` and `deriv`  and pass (possibly anonymous) instances of derived classes to the Newton class invocation.

---

This could look like (I'm not sure that all details are correct, these are just code fragments to illustrate the idea)

```
interface Function {
     public double eval(double x);
     public double deriv(double);
}

class Example1 implements Function {
     @override
     public double eval(double x) { return x*(x+3)+1; }
     @override
     public double deriv(double) { return 2*x+3; }
}

....

Solver solver1 = new Newton(new Example1(),x0);
....
Solver solver2 = new Newton(new Function(){
     @override
     public double eval(double x) { return cos(x); }
     @override
     public double deriv(double) { return -sin(x); }
}, x0);
```

Comment: Or use Google Guava's [functional idioms](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained)

Comment: Im not getting exactly what you mean. You want me to create an interface "Function" which has two methods - one for the function itself and one for its derivate. But what do you mean by "pass instances of derived classes to the newton class invocation"?

Comment: Added some code fragments. I had some working code along these principles for the regula falsi method, but have not found it again.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I didnt even know i could initiate an object of an interface. Im still at the very beginning of understanding java.

Comment: It's not really that. It is creating an anonymous class with the provided method implementations and instantiating an object of that class. You will, as example, find this construction often in Event- and ActionListeners. It's the closest to functors/lambda expressions without actually being able to use them.